# How to create a Java object of my type from a predefined set of classes?

Tags: java

I need a hint as to how to solve this problem I have, so I can make a start on this.

I have these 3 classes (cannot be changed or modified):

- GraphDescriptor
- NodeDescriptor
- LinkDescriptor

**GraphDescriptor:**

```
public class GraphDescriptor {
    public Set<NodeDescriptor> nodes;

    public GraphDescriptor() {
        nodes = new HashSet<NodeDescriptor>();
    }

    public Set<NodeDescriptor> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    public void setNodes(Set<NodeDescriptor> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }
}
```

**NodeDescriptor:**

```
public class NodeDescriptor {
    private Set<LinkDescriptor> links;

    public NodeDescriptor() {
        links = new HashSet<LinkDescriptor>();
    }

    public Set<LinkDescriptor> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(Set<LinkDescriptor> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }
}
```

**LinkDescriptor:**

```
public class LinkDescriptor {
    private NodeDescriptor sourceNode; //a Descriptor for the source node of the link
    private NodeDescriptor destinationNode; // a Descriptor for the destination node of the link

    public LinkDescriptor() {
    }

    public NodeDescriptor getSourceNode() {
        return sourceNode;
    }

    public void setSourceNode(NodeDescriptor sourceNode) {
        this.sourceNode = sourceNode;
    }

    public NodeDescriptor getDestinationNode() {
        return destinationNode;
    }

    public void setDestinationNode(NodeDescriptor destinationNode) {
        this.destinationNode = destinationNode;
    }

}
```

And I have MY classes myGraph, Nodes, Links, Node and Link :

**myGraph:**

```
        public class MyGraph {

            protected Nodes nodes;
            protected Links links;
            protected String name;

            public Nodes getNodes() {
                return nodes;
            }

            public void setNodes(Nodes value) {
                this.nodes = value;
            }

            public Links getLinks() {
                return links;
            }

           public void setLinks(Links value) {
                this.links = value;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String value) {
                this.name = value;
           }
    }
```

**Nodes:**

```
    public class Nodes {

        protected List<Nodes.Node> node;

        public List<Nodes.Node> getNode() {
            if (node == null) {
                node = new ArrayList<Nodes.Node>();
            }
            return this.node;
        }
```

**Node:**

```
        public static class Node {

            protected String name;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String value) {
                this.name = value;
            }
    }
```

**Links:**

```
        public class Links {

            protected List<Links.Link> link;

            public List<Links.Link> getLink() {
                if (link == null) {
                    link = new ArrayList<Links.Link>();
                }
                return this.link;
            }
    }
```

**Link**

```
public static class Link {

        protected String name;
        protected String source;
        protected String destination;


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String value) {
            this.name = value;
        }
        public String getSource() {
            return source;
        }

        public void setSource(String value) {
            this.source = value;
        }

        public String getDestination() {
            return destination;
        }

        public void setDestination(String value) {
            this.destination = value;
        }
}
```

I need to create a *new graph object of my type (myGraph)* given a an instance of *GraphDescriptor*.

The problem I have is since the descriptors (node or link) don't have a name, I can't find a way to interconnect them.

For example: First, I can start by creating a MyGraph graph, then I can create a new Node for each NodeDescriptor belonging to the set of GraphDescriptor. And for each NodeDescripor I can loop through all it's LinkDescriptors,set this Node as source and create a new Node as destination. And so on until the last Node, but at the end I will have separate "sub systems" (each iteration): a node connected with its nodes's destinations for each iteration but not a whole interconnected system, as I don't know how to link them.

I also thought about creating a new class, that has a Node and a NodeDescriptor for example.

---

EDIT: My proposed solution:

```
public class TEST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GraphDescriptor graphD = new GraphDescriptor();
        Set<NodeDescriptor> nodesD = new HashSet<NodeDescriptor>();

        //NODE1
        NodeDescriptor nodeD1 = new NodeDescriptor();
        NodeDescriptor nodeD2 = new NodeDescriptor();
        NodeDescriptor nodeD3 = new NodeDescriptor();

        Set<LinkDescriptor> linksD1 = new HashSet<LinkDescriptor>();
        Set<LinkDescriptor> linksD2 = new HashSet<LinkDescriptor>();
        Set<LinkDescriptor> linksD3 = new HashSet<LinkDescriptor>();

        LinkDescriptor linkD12 = new LinkDescriptor();
        LinkDescriptor linkD13 = new LinkDescriptor();

        //LINKD12
        linkD12.setSourceNode(nodeD1);
        linkD12.setDestinationNode(nodeD2);

        //LINK13
        linkD13.setSourceNode(nodeD1);
        linkD13.setDestinationNode(nodeD3);     

        linksD1.add(linkD12);
        linksD1.add(linkD13);

        nodeD1.setLinks(linksD1);

        //NODE2
        LinkDescriptor linkD23 = new LinkDescriptor();
        linkD23.setSourceNode(nodeD2);
        linkD23.setDestinationNode(nodeD3);
        linksD2.add(linkD23);

        nodeD2.setLinks(linksD2);

        //NODE3
        LinkDescriptor linkD31 = new LinkDescriptor();
        linkD31.setSourceNode(nodeD3);
        linkD31.setDestinationNode(nodeD1);

        linksD3.add(linkD31);

        nodeD3.setLinks(linksD3);

        nodesD.add(nodeD1);
        nodesD.add(nodeD2);
        nodesD.add(nodeD3);

        graphD.setNodes(nodesD);


        MyGraph mygraph = convertGraph(graphD, "myGraph");

        System.out.println("MY GRAPH");

        //print NODES
        System.out.println("NODES");
        for(Node node: mygraph.getNodes().getNode()){
            System.out.println(node.getName());
        }

        //print LINKS
        System.out.println();
        for(Link link: mygraph.getLinks().getLink()) {
            System.out.println(link.getName()+" Source: "+link.getSource()+" Destination: "+ link.getDestination() );
        }

    }

    public static MyGraph convertGraph(GraphDescriptor graphD, String name) {

        MyGraph myGraph = new MyGraph();
        Nodes nodes = new Nodes();
        Links links = new Links();  

        Map<NodeDescriptor,String> nodeDName = new HashMap<NodeDescriptor,String>();

        myGraph.setName(name);

        int nodeN = 1;
        for(NodeDescriptor nodeD : graphD.getNodes()) {

            Node node = new Node();
            node.setName("Node"+nodeN);
            nodes.getNode().add(node);

            nodeDName.put(nodeD, node.getName());
            nodeN++;
        }

        int linkN = 1;
        for(NodeDescriptor nodeD : graphD.getNodes()) {

            for (LinkDescriptor linkD : nodeD.getLinks()) {

                Link link = new Link();

                link.setName("Link"+linkN);
                link.setDestination(nodeDName.get(linkD.getDestinationNode()));
                link.setSource(nodeDName.get(linkD.getSourceNode()));

                linkN++;
                links.getLink().add(link);
            }
        }

        myGraph.setLinks(links);
        myGraph.setNodes(nodes);
        return myGraph;
    }
```

}

Comment: Please show us the code with your approach

Comment: Hi @Maia, thanks for the reply. I think I solve the problem, what do you think? I've updated the post. If you think I can improve the solution, please let me know :)

Comment: You should not edit solution into question, if you like views on a work solution you need to use the codereview site. If you like to answer your own question, you should post it as an answer, see [tour] to learn more.